How to get Vercel Deployment ID in github actions
How to get Vercel deployment ID in github actions
I have deployment in vercel. Deployment URL has been created,
using these commands to build and deploy.
vercel build --debug
DEPLOYMENT_URL=$(vercel deploy --prebuilt --yes)
echo "DEPLOYMENT_URL=${DEPLOYMENT_URL}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
How to get deployment ID in github actions. Is there any api through which we can directly get vercel deployment ID.

https://vercel.com/docs/rest-api/endpoints/deployments#get-a-deployment-by-id-or-url maybe?

While using vercel api link I'm getting Redirecting... as response could you please help in resolving this @BenjaminW.

When we use vercel api make sure while writing deployment URL in the api request remove the https:// other wise you will get INFINITE_LOOP_DETECTED as response.
So finally by using this vercel api you can get the deployment ID.

When we use vercel api make sure while writing deployment URL in the api request remove the https:// other wise you will get INFINITE_LOOP_DETECTED as response. So finally by using this vercel api you can get the deployment ID.
